# HP dv6 graphic chip high temperatur

Tags: hp, ati, temperature, dv6

I have a HP dv6-6180eg with an HD 6770m graphic chip. The driver for the ATI card works fine.

But I have some problems with the temperatur. Out of my fan comes mostly cool air and my CPUs are around 50 degrees. I am more concerned about my ATI card. Although I am not using it, it still warms up very quickly. 
I already deactivated the card via BIOS but still no improvement.

What can I do?

Comment: how do you know it's the gfx card that seems to be hot and how can you tell the temperature? are you using any software to monitor the temperature?

Comment: Yes, with sensors

Comment: Ok, to be quite frank, I am guessing that this is the ATI chip, but the area left of my touchpad is very hot (also the surface)

Comment: Can I provide you with any particular information? @ericosg

Comment: Are you using lm-sensors? Are you getting precice readings for your gfx card? When you say you deactivated the card, what do you mean? Naturally you always use it if you can see stuff on your screen and heavy 3D usage would have it hotter.

Comment: that's my sensors output:

`$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +54.0°C  (crit = +99.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +55.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +53.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +54.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
`

Comment: I meant with deactivation, that I only use my integrated chip. 

`$ aticonfig --pxl 
PowerXpress: Integrated GPU is active (Power-Saving mode).`

Comment: The question really seemed to be, if it's the ATI chip which causes the heat. @ericosg

Answer (score 2):

Install Jupiter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

And then change it to power saving or power on demand mode. Works great for me and many others who have overheating CPU/GPU issues (I have a DV7).

If you're not willing to install things without knowing about them I'd suggest reading up about it on [OmgUbuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/02/jupiter-awesome-netbook-powerconfig-appleta) seeing as there have been many reviews of not only increased battery life for laptops but also reduced heat issues as is your case (you can monitor it yourself if not convinced by checking the temperatures you get in Power Saving mode, or Power on Demand mode)

Reading the description on the [Jupiter website](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/) is a great idea as well as it gives you clear information on the way the applet works and how it could be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your laptop is clean on the inside.

I also own a DV6 and notice that it gets hot when the fans are not performing well.
Air circulation is vital, and fans must maintain good speeds.

Try see if you can clean it a bit without opening it up. I use compressed air blowing in key locations so that the dust/dirt can come out, while holding the fan blades as not to cause them to spin and create voltage that might interfere with the motherboard.

Naturally, while off.

If this yields results then perhaps you are due for a better cleaning in the future and avoiding dusty areas for your laptop to suck up.

Comment: Thank you! I already did that several times... Can't there be any other solution? You didn't experience any problems with your dv6?

Comment: unfortunately none that i know of. Try other sensors and other sensing software maybe. Bootable CDs with their own monitoring tools (i.e. Hiren's) can perhaps show a more reliable measurement, or BIOS monitoring.

Comment: Ok, I will try some of those. Thanks for your kind help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues with heat on my DV6 , and found a simple but perhaps not awesome solution.

Logging in using "Ubuntu 2D", i.e. disabling Composite effects and such. Computer is fully usable but with fewer graphic goodies.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, DV6 uses similar integrated ALU like my ASUS K53T, on my system with amd drivers installed, both the CPU and the GPU hover around the same temps, usually 45C and 65C max under sustained load.